# How to mock StreamReader in NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi, moq

I am trying to use NUnit and Moq for writing unit tests for my sample project. I have a service class like below:

[SentimentService.cs:](https://github.com/Team-Glare/CELT2/blob/main/celt2/API/CELTAPI/Services/SentimentService.cs)

```
public class SentimentService : ISentimentService
{
    private readonly IStreamReader _reader;
    private readonly IServerClient _serverClient;

    public SentimentService(IStreamReader reader, IServerClient serverClient)
    {
        _reader = reader;
        _serverClient = serverClient;
    }


    public async Task<string> CalculateSentimentFromTextFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var input = "";
        using (StreamReader streamReader = _reader.GetReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            input = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
        }

        var result = await _serverClient.PostAsync<SentimentResult, string>($"submit_string", input);

        return result.label;
    }
}
```

I tried of using Moq like below:

```
[Test]
public async Task CalculateSentimentFromTextFileEquality()
{
    var mockFormFile = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var mockStreamReader = new Mock<IStreamReader>();
    var mockServerClient = new Mock<IServerClient>();

    var mockResult = new SentimentResult
    {
        label = "Positive"
    };

    mockStreamReader.Setup(o => o.GetReader(mockFormFile.Object.OpenReadStream()));

    mockServerClient.Setup(o => o.PostAsync<SentimentResult, string>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(mockResult);

    var sut = new SentimentService(mockStreamReader.Object, mockServerClient.Object);
    var result = await sut.CalculateSentimentFromTextFile(mockFormFile.Object);

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("Positive"));
}
```

But, getting the below error:

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us which line is the #35 in the `SentimentServiceTest`?

Answer (score 1):

This setup:

```
 mockStreamReader.Setup(o => o.GetReader(mockFormFile.Object.OpenReadStream()));
```

does not return any object and thus when calling this in SUT:

```
StreamReader streamReader = _reader.GetReader(file.OpenReadStream()
```

will return a null object.

However, `StreamReader` has parameterless constructors, which means you have to provide the real file path/stream if you want to mock it. One way to handle the `StreamReader` is to create an interface which later can be implemented by a wrapper of `StreamReader`.

```
public interface IStreamReader : IDisposable
{
    string ReadToEnd();
    void Close();
}
```

Creation of `IStreamReader` is made by a factory:

```
public interface IStreamReaderFactory
{
    IStreamReader GetReader(Stream stream);
}
```

Your SUT can be modified to:

```
public class SentimentService : ISentimentService
{
    private readonly IStreamReaderFactory _readerFactory;
    private readonly IServerClient _serverClient;

    public SentimentService(IStreamReaderFactory readerFactory, IServerClient serverClient)
    {
        _readerFactory = readerFactory;
        _serverClient = serverClient;
    }


    public async Task<string> CalculateSentimentFromTextFile(IFormFile file)
    {
         var input = "";
         using (IStreamReader streamReader = _readerFactory.GetReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
         {
             input = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
             streamReader.Close();
         }

         var result = await _serverClient.PostAsync<SentimentResult, string>($"submit_string", input);

         return result.label;
    }
}
```

The test code should now be able to setup `IStreamReader` properly.

```
var mockStreamReader = new Mock<IStreamReader>();
var mockStreamReaderFactory = new Mock<IStreamReaderFactory>();

mockStreamReaderFactory.Setup(o => o.GetReader(It.IsAny<Stream>())).Returns(mockStreamReader.Object);
```